# How do I clear or delete or make null SPS-Birthday and SPS-Anniversary?

Tags: powershell, user-profile-property

This property is used for employees in a web part on our intranet homepage. We had some employees leave the company then come back as contractors or consultants. Their accounts were reused in some cases.

Is there a solution for this I can use in a script? I'm most comfortable in powershell but i'm open.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but try this as a good start.

First, Install SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module using the following command:

```
# Install PowerShell PnP Module if not installed:
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

Next, update the user's property using the [Set-PnPUserProfileProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpuserprofileproperty?view=sharepoint-ps) commandlet

```
# make sure you connect to the -admin site: 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -SPOManagementShell -SkipTenantAdminCheck
        
# Force save by setting an empty birthday and Anniversary values
Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account "user@domain.com" -PropertyName "SPS-Birthday" -Value -Value [String]::Empty
Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account "user@domain.com" -PropertyName "SPS-Anniversary" -Value -Value [String]::Empty
```